# 2 linq queries to same gridview

Tags: c#, linq, web

I would like to "combine" to linq queries into the same gridview. Though I don't think I could use innerjoin on this.
The queries get orders from the database, and I have 2 tables with orders from different places. 
In the gridview I want to display all orders from first table and second table.
Like this:

```
OrderID - Item - Amount etc ---From table 1
OrderID - Item - Amount etc ---From table 2
etc..
```

My current query for getting orders from the first table are:

```
var query = from o in db.Orders
            join y in db.OrderLines on o.OrderID equals y.OrderID
            join x in db.Products on y.ItemNumber equals x.ItemNumber
            where o.AccountNumber == AppSession.CurrentLoginTicket.AccountNumber
            select new
            {
                o.OrderID,
                o.AxaptaSalesId,
                y.ItemNumber,
                x.Name,
                x.ProductFormatName,
                y.Quantity,
                y.Price,
                Status = dltRep.getOrderStatus(o.OrderID, o.AxaptaSalesId, y.ItemNumber).Substring(0, dltRep.getOrderStatus(o.OrderID, o.AxaptaSalesId, y.ItemNumber).LastIndexOf("|")),
                Levering = dltRep.getOrderStatus(o.OrderID, o.AxaptaSalesId, y.ItemNumber).Substring(dltRep.getOrderStatus(o.OrderID, o.AxaptaSalesId, y.ItemNumber).LastIndexOf("|")).Replace("|", "")
            };
```

The other table would have the same information. It's named AxSale.

I hope this is possible and someone could help me out :)

**EDIT: new "problem"**

I wan't to get the variable createdDate to be the first element x.CreatedDate in either the first linq seq. or the second.
How do I do this?

```
var created = purchases.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).
                Select(x => new { x.CreatedDate, x.LineSupplierAccountNO }).
                GroupBy(x => x.LineSupplierAccountNO);

if (created.Count() > 1)
{
    created = purchases.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).
                Select(x => new { x.CreatedDate, x.LineSupplierAccountNO }).
                GroupBy(x => x.LineSupplierAccountNO);
}

var createdDate = created.FirstOrDefault();
```

### **Solution code:**

```
var created = purchases.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => x);

if (created.GroupBy(x => x.LineSupplierAccountNO).Count() > 1)
{
    created = purchases.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => x);
}

var createdDate = created.First().CreatedDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` operator to join results with same fields. Here is example from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
public void Linq49() 
{ 
    List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 
    List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList(); 

    var productFirstChars = 
        from p in products 
        select p.ProductName[0]; 
    var customerFirstChars = 
        from c in customers 
        select c.CompanyName[0]; 

    var uniqueFirstChars = productFirstChars.Union(customerFirstChars); 

    Console.WriteLine("Unique first letters from Product names and Customer names:"); 
    foreach (var ch in uniqueFirstChars) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ch); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you help with another linq "problem" I got.
I have edited my topic first post, with the new code

Comment: I don't really get the CreatedDate sent to the createdDate variable.
This is want it returns: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler+Group`2[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String]]

Comment: try to change `created.FirstOrDefault();` to `created.Select(x=>x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();` and look while debugging `created` or `createdDate` is not null

Comment: I says "Cannot resolve symbol CreatedDate". It doesn't appear either in the intellisense when doing the select.

Comment: This grouping is making this even worse. I found a solution to the problem where I could get the date created.FirstOrDefault().First().CreatedDate, but now it's not sorting it right.
I want to select the oldeste CreatedDate if there are more rows with the same LineSupplierAccountNO and the newest CreatedDate if there more rows but with different LineSupplierAccountNO.

Comment: okay, I solved it after some time struggling. I've added my solution to the topic post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx)

Try this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/11/union-operator-part-12.aspx)

Comment: Reniuz was a little bit faster to post than you, thanks for the help. Union was the solution :)